# Ruling out stable ud quark matter with neutron star atmospheres

Tags: quarks, neutron-stars

[up-down quark matter](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.120.222001) is a hypothetical form of matter that is more stable than regular matter and is among the more "mainstream" exotic matter proposals. Small pieces of it would act like very heavy nuclei and allow the periodic table to extend "forever" as well as isotopes of "unlimited" mass. Water could be denser than gold.

A ud quark nugget could grow by fusing with nuclei. This charges the nugget and electrostatic repulsion stops the fusion *if the nugget is small enough*. If the nugget approaches the size of a hydrogen atom (atomic mass ~$10^{14}$), it screens itself with electrons, fusion continues, and it grows endlessly. Also, the positive charge of the growing nugget is kept in check by electron capture. The energy released would [slow down](http://www-astro.physics.ox.ac.uk/%7Egarret/teaching/lecture7-2012.pdf) the reaction, at least on Earth.

If ud nuggets are stable they are likely to exist in [more massive neutron stars](https://inspirehep.net/files/9ab3e474368faa1bb5233f211cfcee3b). Once formed, a nugget would eat the entire star. The fusion energy released is not sufficient to push away atoms/nuclei for very long against the extreme gravity, even atoms at the surface.

Normal neutron stars have atmospheres of normal elements such as [ionized carbon](https://astronomy.com/news/2009/11/carbon-atmosphere-discovered-on-neutron-star). But a giant ud nugget would eat any accreting gas immediately. So am I correct that a stable atmosphere on a large neutron star would rule out ud nugget stability?

Comment: This is not the correct venue for asking "am I correct", but a question and answer site on mainstream physics. IMO what you discuss should be written up and expanded as a paper and submitted to peer review, Peer review is also for evaluating the correctness of the paper.

Comment: This is a valid question. Wang 2021 suggests only larger neutron stars might have them.  The real question is why udQM nuggets aren't called [Jumbonium](https://theinfosphere.org/Jumbonium), and the answer is obviously they should be.